# Adding a resource image to a picture box not working with my.resources

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've seen the question asked and answered many times and none of the solutions seem to be working for me and it's frustrating. As a hobby programmer I enjoy the challenge of solving problems I come up with and can usually figure out the answer, but this time I'm stumped completely

Background: I have a form with a number of comboboxes from which I read selected values and pass them to a picture box on a second form which displays on a secondary monitor. Initially I used the full path to the directory where the images were stored and the pictures displayed/performed perfectly, but realised if I used the programme on another computer it wouldn't be able to do that so I added the images as resources in the programme

What I tried:

```
Dim firstplace As String = Form1.first_place_list.SelectedItem
Dim firstplace_image As Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(firstplace)
    first_place_flag.Image = firstplace_image
```

I also tried:

```
 Dim firstplace As String = Form1.first_place_list.SelectedItem
 Dim firstplace_image As Bitmap = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(firstplace)
        first_place_flag.Image = firstplace_image
```

What worked (for both versions of above):

```
 Dim firstplace As String = Form1.first_place_list.SelectedItem
 Dim firstplace_image As Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Bermuda")
 first_place_flag.Image = firstplace_image
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use default instances of Forms, which is the first problem you have to solve. The second problem is that you have `Option Strict` set to `Off`, this has to be resolved ASAP

Comment: If something doesn't work, you need to explain what actually happens. If there's a compilation error or run-time exception, you need to tell us what and where.

Comment: Did you actually debug your code to see what the value of `firstplace` is? Presumably it is not `"Bermuda"`. Maybe you need to be using `Text` rather than `SelectedItem`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, my apologies, the "what I tried code" produces a picturebox with no image, the "what worked" code shows the image exactly as I want it to, no run-time or compiler errors. The firstflag variable is getting populated correctly from the combobox, but getobject isn't retrieving the resource referenced by firstflag, e.g. Bermuda, so getObject("Bermuda") works, but getObject(firstflag) doesn't. I know it's probably something simple I'm missing

Comment: What you describe simply isn't possible. You may think it contains that value but it doesn't. If it did then it would work because a `String` is a `String`, regardless of where it comes from. Debug your code. Set a breakpoint and actually look at the value.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you, you were right, somehow the comboboxes had a space before each line so instead of looking for "Bermuda" the code was looking for " Bermuda" Major DOH! moment on my part

Comment: That's why you've ALWAYS got to debug. Look for the obvious things first but, if things still don't work as you expect, use the debugger to challenge your assumptions.